# Noobie programer. Bar filling game

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am currently working on a mini-game in C++. I'm using Code::Blocks. Here's how the game is supposed to go, A bar shows on the screen. It will fill up. When ever the user presses the space bar, the bar empties. This bar program is a small program I am writing to a larger story based program. So I am trying to make it so that if the bar empties, the story goes one way, but it the bar fills it goes another. The problem I am having is, I cannot seem to get the bar to fill or empty. I'm pretty new to programming. Any help would be appreciated. 
The bar I am trying currently to make:

```
##################################################
#MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM                       #
##################################################
```

The bar I plan on making after I've gotten the bar filling and emptying all figured out:

```
##################################################
#MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM                       #
#MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM                       #
#MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM                       #
#MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM                       #
##################################################
```

All the 'M' characters are to be the characters that empty and fill the bar.

The following is the code I've gotten so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch = 'a';
    cout << "##################################################" << endl;
    cout << "#";
    for (int j = 25; j < 50 || j > 0; j++)
    {
        while (j >=0 || j <= 50)
        {
            cin >> ch
            if (ch == ' ')
            {
                j--;
                ch = 'a';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "M";
                delay(200);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "#" << endl;

    return 0;
}

//Output
/*
##################################################
##

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.156 s
Press any key to continue.
*/
```

Comment: Can you explain what your loops are doing? They seem unnecessarily complicated to just count up to some number of 'M's.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop you are using `while (j >=0 || j <= 50)` is an infinite loop. You might want to change that into `while (j >= 0 && j <= 50)` in order for it to be in your wanted range.
Also your `for (int j = 25; j < 50 || j > 0; j++)` translates into an infinite loop because j is always going to be either less than 50, which translates into all the negative numbers, or bigger than 0, which translates into all the positive numbers. You would want to change that into `for (int j = 25; j < 50 && j > 0; j++)`.
However I think you should rethink the algorithm you're trying to solve this by. Best of luck and I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int j = 25; j > 50 || j < 0; j++)
```

Your for loop will never execute, because we see j is initialized to 25 `int j = 25`, and `25 > 50` evaluates to false, as well as `25 < 0`, so it exits immediately.

It might be helpful to look into char[][] arrays for displaying such a bar.. You would first look into [char arrays](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/) and then [two dimensional arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/). Doing so would allow you to have a row / column approach to the problem, and you could backtrack very easily (say you wanted to "empty the bar" a few spaces if they pressed a certain key)

Comment: Shit. That was a terrible mistake. I accidentally deleted your whole comment. Sorry, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Now your for loop condition is always true:
    for (int j = 25; j < 50 || j > 0; j++)
you want
    for (int j = 25; j < 50 && j > 0; j++)
presumably

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `for` loop, you'll see that the condition is always false.

Then, the `if (ch = ' ')` condition will always be true. You might want to do `if (ch == ' ')` to test the value instead of assigning it.

I think what you're doing is unecessarly complicated. Try to re think your algorithm.

Comment: My pleasure. Don't forget to validate if it solved the problem.